The probability of sample path of brownian motion within a \epsilon-distance of a smooth function
It's well known that for all continuous function $f:[0,1]\, \to \mathbb{R}$, we can show that $P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_{t}-f(t)|<\epsilon)>0$, where $P$ is the probability measure under which $(B_t)_{t \leq 0}$ is a standard Brownian Motion. Now I want to know how to estimate $P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_{t}-f(t)|<\epsilon)$, where $f$ is a smooth function. I guess the probability is
\begin{align}ce^{-\frac{\gamma}{\epsilon^2}}+o(e^{-\frac{\gamma}{\epsilon^2}})\end{align} as $\epsilon \to 0$, and I will explain why I guess this.
When $f=0$, we can define a stopping time $\tau_{\epsilon}=\inf\{t>0:|B_t|>\epsilon\}$, and $P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_{t}|<\epsilon)=P(\tau_{\epsilon}>1)$. Let
\begin{align}
u(t,x)=P^x(\tau_{\epsilon}>t)
\end{align}
where $P^x$ is the probability measure under which $(B_t)_{t \leq 0}$ is a standard Brownian Motion starting at $x$. Then we can show $u(t,x)$ satisfies the following PDE
\begin{align}
\partial_t u&=\frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2u &\quad |x|<\epsilon \\
u(0,x)&=1 &|x|<\epsilon\\
u(t,x)&=0 &|x|=\epsilon
\end{align}
The PDE can be solved explicitly by Fourier method and we can get the result above, i.e. $P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_{t}|<\epsilon)=ce^{-\frac{\gamma}{\epsilon^2}}+o(e^{-\frac{\gamma}{\epsilon^2}})$ and the constant $c$, $\gamma$ can be explicitly calculated.
Now I want to find the probability $P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_{t}-f(t)|<\epsilon)$ for a general smooth function $f$, at least the asymptotic behaviour with explicitly determined constant $c$, $\gamma$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. We can define the stopping time $\tau_\epsilon$ similarly. However, since $f(t)$ depends on the time $t$, I have difficulties in finding a similar PDE, and I wonder whether a PDE for the problem can be found, or it can be solved in other ways, e.g. by approximation on dyadic points.
